# AVAudioPlayer: Sounds overlapping

Tags: iphone, audio, avaudioplayer, avfoundation

i made a simple app where i can record myself and then sample what i've recorded. Since i like spamming buttons, i tried it with my own app. The result was, about 20 the same sounds of myself talking overlapping and creating a horrible mess. How can i prevent such thing in the future?

That's my code:

.h

```
-(IBAction)record {

        TempRecFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithString:@"VoiceFile"]]];

        recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:TempRecFile settings:nil error:nil];
        [recorder setDelegate:self];
        [recorder prepareToRecord];
        [recorder record];

}

-(IBAction)playback {

    [recorder stop];

    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:TempRecFile error:nil];
    player.volume = 1;
    [player play];

}
```

Later on i want to play multiple sounds attached to multiple buttons and if all of those start overlapping, the users ears would probably start bleeding very shortly... :(

The problem with multiple sound buttons would be: I would need to restrict every sound to overlapping only with itself. How can I do such thing?

Comment: It would probably be wise to try to reformat your code to avoid the horizontal scrollbar. In Chrome under Windows XP, I'm measuring room for 81 or 82 characters (I'm not sure whether the last one really fits), so I'd suggest just following the old "80 column" rule of thumb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Playback method, disable the button first thing. When you init your class, set your class to be the delegate for the AVAudioPlayer and implement the protocol [AVAudioPlayerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/AVAudioPlayerDelegate), specifically you want to catch the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully: event. In the event, re-enable the button.

So, this will disable the button, play the sound, and when the sound is done playing enable the button.

Now, for multiple buttons, just do the same thing for each. The catch is you'll need to keep track of an AVAudioPlayer for each button and know which player goes with which button. An NSDictionary could be used to keep the list of players, along with key values.

EDIT: To stop previous playback and start over at the beginning...

Declare an AVPlayer at the class level rather than create a new one for each button press. When the button is pressed you can send it a seekToTime message to start over at the beginning. For multiple buttons have multiple class level AVPlayers.

Edit: If you use AVAudioPlayer class you could do the same thing setting the currentTime property.

Comment: I don't want the sound to finish playing succsesfully. I want it to stop the current sound (of this button) it's playing and start over.

Comment: I added a way to do this to my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: I got mixed up for a minute there and started talking about AVPlayers, so I added how to do it with AVAudioPlayers.

Comment: oh, thanks will do the declaration of the Players right now. Btw, how should i use the seekToTime? like [myPlayer seekToTime:0.0]; ? One more question: How can i make a player of button stop, when an other button player is playing? tnx for the help :D

Comment: I upped all your comments etc, although im still awaiting some other answers.

Comment: To use seekToTime take a look at [Seeking—Repositioning the Playhead](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW6).

Comment: To make a stop button link it to a method that sets your AVPlayer's rate property to zero. To start it again, set rate back to 1. Again you could have one per player or have the method set all your AVPlayers' rates to zero to stop all playing.